# graphviz/dot graph: Order nodes within a cluster/a subgraph

Tags: graph, graphviz, dot

Help sort nodes within subgraphs or clusters such as subgraph A and B below.

```
graph {
    splines=line;
    subgraph cluster_0 {
        label="Subgraph A";
        a; b; c
    }

    subgraph cluster_1 {
        label="Subgraph B";
        d; e;
    }

    a -- e;
    a -- d;
    b -- d;
    b -- e;
    c -- d;
    c -- e;
}
```

This graph is not desirable. Help us sort "a", "b", "c" and "d", and "e" from left-to-right, please.

https://graphs.grevian.org/resources/static/images/example6a.png

Answer (score 0):

I found this difficult to do, and don't guarantee that it works with a more complex graph.  In addition to getting the nodes in the desired sequence, it is quite difficult to position clusters where you want.  That said, this:

```
graph {
    splines=line;
    rankdir=LR

    subgraph cluster_0 {
        label="Subgraph A";
        rank=same
        a -- b -- c [style=invis]
    }

    subgraph cluster_1 {
        label="Subgraph B";
        rank=same
        d -- e  [style=invis]
    }

  edge[constraint=false]
    a -- e;
    a -- d;
    b -- d;
    b -- e;
    c -- d;
    c -- e;
}
```

produces this:

[image]